# how to create a hyperlink for file download in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, download

I have some files stored on my machine. When a user wants to generate a link the page should generate a hyperlink. This hyperlink can be used by any other user so as to download the file

Comment: What do you mean "generate a link"?

Comment: the list of all files are displayed on the page..the user must be able to get a link to that file so he/she can share it among thier friends.

Comment: If you are getting a list of the files and displaying it, then you should already know what the URLs are. Just list them along with the file names.

Comment: i will be having the physical path to the files, how do i convert it into a virtual path and display it as a hyperlink?? ..i dont want to reveal my physical path to the public users

Comment: @SridharPratik if the page that server them is on the same directory with the files, then you only need to give the filename. If its on different directory, then you need to give the relative path. If its on directory out side the root of the site, then is complicate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a LinkButton and for the click event do the following

your aspx file will have the following

```
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" Text="Download"/>
```

Your code behind will have the following

```
 protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            var fileInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your file text");
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileInBytes))
            {
                long dataLengthToRead = stream.Length;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.BufferOutput = true;
                Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; /// if it is text or xml
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "yourfilename");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataLengthToRead.ToString());
                stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
            }
            Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing in this answer regarding "generating a link"

Comment: Well man, I did the final effect that he wanted to do. Yes this can be 'regarded' as a generating a link to download. The only thing that he has to do is to attach the event to the the linkbutton on click at the point when he wanted to generate a link. And my understanding is when he say generate a link, he meant how to create. My answer is good enough for him.

Comment: @DanHunex Your answer is use `"text/xml"` that is make the file to not download correct - second the BufferOutput must be false - also is not good to use a page to download a file - now for a simple link you make a full complex code, why ? a simple hyperlink with a correct path is done the job. Also you suppose that the file is in memory, but is say that is on disk, this is read the file from memory, where you say "your file text".

Comment: @Aristos how can you do it if you have a text stored in sql db? Well I did for a general case. Yes if you already know the file name and its location , it is easy as you said. But if the file is to be generated at runtime, my way is the way to go

Comment: @DanHunex Here is say files on disk, not text, not db - in this answer you do not even load a file from disk, as the question ask!

Comment: @Aristos I agree with that. What he should do is to have placeholder for the link and then create the the hyperlink  on the code behind and inject it in the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

you can direct link the hyperlink with the file if you know the address but this is limited by the browser. eg. if pdf reader is installed on the client then the pdf will not be downloaded instead it will be shown. A good solution would be to have a seperate page for downloading files. just pass filename in querystring and in the pageload event just outpit the file in response stream.This way you can use url say dwnld.aspx?filename.ext

Now you can generate urls via the above logic.